# How to display word document on a aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to display my updated document to the `aspx` page. I searched a lot for this. But I am not able to find any proper way. I have tried so many things.

1. I have tried `Microsoft Interop dll` to convert word document to `pdf`
   and then I display pdf file to the page it worked but found Issue
   that Interop dll cannot be used on production machine. And other
   thing Interop dlls cannot be copy to project.
2. I am updating my word document using OpenXml. So I tried `OpenXmlPowerTool` to convert Document to Html. But It is not converting document properly. Images are not visible some formatting of the text are not proper.

The other problem is that I cannot use third party tool which I have to purchase. I can use only open source product which are freely available.

Can anyone knows how can I do this?
Any suggestions will be appreciated..!

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "display"? Why do you not simply allow downloading the word document?

Comment: No I cant do that. It is a SharePoint app. In which document is being updated according to some data and after updating it will be displayed to the user as a report. After that user will save or download the document.

Comment: Why not "...after updating, the user will download the document and save it or open it for display" ? Sorry to iterate the question, but I really don't understand why you are trying to convert it into a pdf or HTML. You do realize, that if you want to display it on the user's computer, it has to be downloaded to that computer, right?

Comment: User needs to confirm that the data are perfect before saving report to the document library.

Comment: Actually the document will directly saved to the document library download is not allowed.

Comment: Fine. Then allow them to download it and use Word to view it, after which you ask them if they're happy and save it in the document library?

Comment: It will be much more difficult to perform in SharePoint Autohosted app. It is nearly impossible according to my experience. I will have to code using interop dll for this.

Comment: Can you have your documents in ODF, and use [WebODF](http://webodf.org/)? Word supports that format.

Comment: Just to confirm, you tried http://powertools.codeplex.com/, and it did not work?

Comment: if you have SharePoint already, you could look into OfficeWebApps. I was able to use OWAS to load Word docs into a web page. It also gives you the ability to edit and save those files as well.

Comment: @Michael Yes I used powertools.

Comment: @mmeasor I have SharePoint in my machine. Can you tell me how to use OfficeWebApps?

Comment: The way we had it at my old job was running on another server. Then in code you would need to reference the SharePoint Client Side Object Model (CSOM). using that you can get a link to the documents in SharePoint. Then you can code pretty much whatever you want. I would suggest you start here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855124(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use some proprietary libraries (like [aspose](http://www.aspose.com)) for converting it into pdf and show that pdf files for user by adobe acrobat kit ([codeproject howto](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5887/Generate-Thumbnail-Images-from-PDF-Documents)).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, but you need to have your document as a binary array. You can, however, work from here:

```
...
byte[] docFile = null;
...
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Document.doc\"");
Response.ContentType = "application/x-unknown";
Response.BinaryWrite(docFile);
Response.End();
```

Note: application/x-unknown is used to force the browser to prompt the user to open or save